# gitlab-runner cache file size everytime got double in size

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using distributed cache (S3) for gitlab runner. It working fine but everytime the runner executes job and store cache file in S3, the size of file got double. It includes the older cache.zip file in the new cache file.

**gitlab-ci.yml** file:

```
cache:
  key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
  untracked: true
  paths:
    - .m2/repository/
```

runner cache configuration file **config.toml**:

```
  [runners.cache]                              
    Type = "s3"                                
    Path = "runners-cache"                     
    [runners.cache.s3]                                      
      ServerAddress = "s3.amazonaws.com"                    
      AccessKey = "***"                    
      SecretKey = "***"
      BucketName = "***"                     
      BucketLocation = "***"
```